# failed upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kubuntu, 16.04

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 32bit.  trying to upgrade I used kubuntu-devel-release-upgrade, it started work fine, but while it was downloading it was interrupted several times but starting from the cumulative percent of downloaded data, except for the last time that I left from one day to the next. Kubuntu seems to be updated and update-manager does not find any update.  It is like if the system is running 16.04.  What happened?

Comment: I also tried to install using USB (as I have done with 14.04 LTS in several compueters) and there is a boot error message.  I use the same utility, but 16.04 does not start, only 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try doing `sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade`

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, kubuntu-devel-release-upgrade, and sudo update-manager -d (and -p).  None of them finds the new version...